# If you have $\max(a,b)$ and $\min(a,b)$, how would one find expressions for these using addition, subtraction, and absolute value?

Tags: real-analysis

Just a quick question. If you have $\max(a,b)$ and $\min(a,b)$, how would one find expressions for these using addition, subtraction, and absolute value?
My thought process was that suppose $\max(a,b) = a$. Then, $a > b \Rightarrow a-b > 0$. This is an idea I had that I do not know how to continue with.

Answer (score 1):

$max(a,b) = \dfrac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$

Try to get the other one.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: @NickFreeman: On the real axis, $(a+b)/2$ is the point which lies directly between $a$ and $b$; $|a-b|$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$. How can you combine these two values to get the max and min?

Comment: I get what your saying but I don't see how they are being combined. Maybe this is really easy and I am not seeing it.

Comment: Draw in the real line the points $a, b, \frac{a+b}{2}$. The distance from the midpoint to $\max (a,b) $ is $\dfrac{|a-b|}{2}$. Now look at the answer...

Answer (score -1):

$\max(a,b) = \frac{a}{2} + \max(\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}, \frac{b}{2}-\frac{a}{2}) + \frac{b}{2} = \frac{a + b}{2} + \frac{|a - b|}{2} = \frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$

This is because $\max(x,-x) = |x|$

$\min(a,b) = \frac{a}{2} + \min(\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}, \frac{b}{2}-\frac{a}{2}) + \frac{b}{2} = \frac{a + b}{2} - \frac{|a - b|}{2} = \frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$

This is because $\min(x,-x) = -|x|$