# Is there an arithmetic way to determine the greater of 2 numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want to be able to determine the greater of 2 numbers $a$ and $b$ mathematically without using "$<,>$" symbols.

Something like ${(a - b)+(1 - |b - a|)\over 2}\dots = c$.

$c$ being the greater number between $a$ and $b$ or equal to both.

It feels impossible to determine it this way with this amount of information but I'm interested in the subject of information anyway, at least I'll understand why it can't be done :D

Thank you. Feel free to edit the tags and vocabulary used here, I have no idea.

Comment: Either $\max(a,b)$ or $\frac{a+b}2+\frac{|a-b|}2$ works as a definition of $c$, but while they do not contain $<$ or $>$ explicitly, those symbols are part of the definition of both $\max({}\cdot{},{}\cdot{})$ and of $|{}\cdot{}|$.

Comment: Made an edit on your post, please check that it still says what you wanted... Thanks

Comment: Closely related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983544/

Comment: @Arthur Yes I figured that but I'm writing an algorithm to find the GCD of 2 numbers and I'm trying to do it without `if` statements and now I can do it also without any booleans :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?
$$\max(a,b) = \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{|a-b|}{2}$$

Indeed if $a > b$ then $|a-b| = a-b$ and the expression equals $a$, but if $a < b$ then $|a-b| = b-a$ and the expression equals $b$. But of course this is just hiding the inequalities inside the definition of the absolute value, which is:
$$|x| = \begin{cases} x, & \text{if } x \mathrel{\color{red} \ge} 0; \\ -x, & \text{if } x \mathrel{\color{red} \le} 0. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Alternatively, if you use $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ then you can hide the inequality in the positive square root convention instead.

Comment: Holy shit thank you this is perfect. I was almost there, even though I wrote it in the bogus example, I couldn't figure out that |a-b| needed to be halved. I was stuck with a choice between 0 and |a-b| xD. Sometimes indeed the truth lies half-way. Anyway thanks, mathematicians are awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

Finding $\max(x,y)$ cannot be done using the four arithmetic operations only.

Indeed, the result of a chain of arithmetic operations is a rational function of the inputs. Every rational function is smooth, but the function $\max(x,0)$ is not smooth at $x=0$.

Comment: Then in what branch of math is Najib's solution embedded? I told you feel free to edit my tags and vocabulary to a more suitable one.